# Build Jansson 2.7 failed if I copy the directory elsewhere

Tags: c, linux, automake

I'm using Jansson 2.7 for my project. I found something that causes a build failed.

If I try:

```
tar -zxvf jansson-2.7.tar.gz
cd jansson-2.7/
./configure
make
```

Everything is just fine. But If I try:

```
tar -zxvf jansson-2.7.tar.gz
cp jansson-2.7 jansson-2.7-test -r
cd jansson-2.7-test/
./configure
make
```

Configure will success, but make will fail:

```
make
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/bash /home/nick/Downloads/jansson-2.7-test/missing aclocal-1.14 
/home/nick/Downloads/jansson-2.7-test/missing: line 81: aclocal-1.14: command not found
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.14' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
```

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: My only guess is that you're extracting the archive to the same directory, and `configure` is not generating some files because they're already there. I would try, after removing extracted directories, with `mkdir jansson-2.7-test; tar -zxvf jansson-2.7.tar.gz -C jansson-2.7-test; ./configure; make`.

Comment: @BarisDemiray Thanks, that would work. But in my case, I have to put jansson with my project together on a git server. Even if I extract jansson to my project folder and do nothing then commit and push, in a new clone of my project the build problem remains. By the way, if I copy jansson-2.7 to jansson-2.7-test and diff these two folders, it tell me that they are completely the same. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Author of Jansson has replied this question on Jansson users group. Please refer to the following page: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jansson-users/CoE2IPfgSMc

Comment: argh! I get this error if i simply extract and configure/make (although it claims to need 1.15, while my system only has 1.14...)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue simply extracting and trying to run configure/make.  Following the link provided by nick2100, I found the following commands fixed the problem:

```
./configure 
make AUTOCONF=: AUTOHEADER=: AUTOMAKE=: ACLOCAL=: 
make AUTOCONF=: AUTOHEADER=: AUTOMAKE=: ACLOCAL=: install
```